# PHP - Fatal error: Call to a member function super_query() on a non-object

Tags: php, sql

Fatal error: Call to a member function super_query() on a non-object in /mp3.is-great.org/htdocs/modules/profile.php on line 7

This is my profile.php:

```
<?php

if(isset($_REQUEST['username'])) $username = $_REQUEST['username'];

if(!$username) die("User not found!");

$user = $db->super_query("SELECT username, user_id, lastdate, reg_date, banned, info, foto, fullname, playlist, song FROM tan_users WHERE username = '$username'");

if(!$user) die("User not found!");

$row = $db->super_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM tan_favorites WHERE user_id = '" . $user['user_id'] . "'");
$user['favorites'] = $row['count'];

$row = $db->super_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM tan_playlists WHERE user_id = '" . $user['user_id'] . "'");
$user['playlists'] = $row['count'];


$smarty->assign("User", $user);

$action = $_REQUEST['action'];

$smarty->assign("Action", $action);

if($action == 'favorites'){

    $db->query("SELECT source, hash, name FROM tan_favorites WHERE user_id = '" . $user['user_id'] . "'");

    while ($row = $db->get_row($sql_result)){

        $row['play_url'] = play_url($row['hash'], $row['source'], $row['name']);

        $favorites[] = $row;

    }

    $smarty->assign('Favorites', $favorites);

}elseif($action == 'playlists'){

    $db->query("SELECT tan_playlists.id, tan_playlists.foto, tan_playlists.name, tan_users.username, tan_users.fullname FROM tan_playlists LEFT JOIN tan_users ON tan_playlists.user_id = tan_users.user_id WHERE tan_playlists.user_id = '" . $user['user_id'] . "'");

    while ($row = $db->get_row($sql_result)){

        $playlists[] = $row;

    }

    $smarty->assign('Playlists', $playlists);

}else{

    $db->query("SELECT source, hash, name FROM tan_favorites WHERE user_id = '" . $user['user_id'] . "' LIMIT 0,10");

    while ($row = $db->get_row($sql_result)){

        $row['play_url'] = play_url($row['hash'], $row['source'], $row['name']);

        $favorites[] = $row;

    }

    $smarty->assign('Favorites', $favorites);

    $db->query("SELECT tan_playlists.id, tan_playlists.foto, tan_playlists.name, tan_users.username, tan_users.fullname FROM tan_playlists LEFT JOIN tan_users ON tan_playlists.user_id = tan_users.user_id WHERE tan_playlists.user_id = '" . $user['user_id'] . "' ORDER by id DESC LIMIT 0,10");

    while ($row = $db->get_row($sql_result)){

        $playlists[] = $row;

    }

    $smarty->assign('Playlists', $playlists);

}

$smarty->assign("Title", $username);

if($member_id['username'] == $username) $smarty->assign("MEMBER", $member_id);

?>
```

Any ideas why i'd be getting this error?

Safe Mode is off on my hosting, and it's a free host so I can't change php.ini

I'm kinda a PHP noob, any help and link to solve my problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Your non object is the variable `$db`. You never initiate the class. Also note that you're injecting variables into your query, making it **hackable** and **insecure**. Use PDO with prepared statements and bind your variables.

Comment: Make sure you are cleansing your input to avoid SQL Injection Attacks.  Use mysqli_real_escape_string() to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you haven't created the `$db` object.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to initialize your DB-connection like

```
$db = new PDO('host'; 'table', 'user', 'pass');
```

Comment: Where would I put that

Comment: Just before the first use of the variable.